# VS2013 Crashes When Importing Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova

I am using VS2013 and working in a Cordova project. I am attempting to import the BarcodeScanner plugin (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner) but it keeps causing VS to freeze up and eventually force close. I have tried importing via local file as well as Git and both fail with the same result. I have read of this happening to other plugins but can't find any record of this happening with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Stale version - use this instead
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git

If still freezes (it does as of today,) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475833/couldnt-download-cordova-plugin-error-in-visual-studio) alternative worked for me (see accepted answer)