# Couldn't Download Cordova Plugin Error in Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to install plugin for my cordova app in Visual Studio 2015 its giving error:

```
Couldn't download plugin.
```

If I tried to install it using CLI error is:

```
Current Directory is not cordova based project
```

Comment: Which plugin you are trying to add and if you downloading from git, post the Git url.

Comment: Visual Studio Allows us to Install Plugin Directly from Config file. For every core plugin it shows an error like couldn't download plugin

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted.  Seems to be an issue with both the stock plugins list and custom github urls.  Also having the same issue when trying to use `cordova plugin add ...`

Comment: I'm getting the same for custom plugins from git specifically
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git the marked answer does not resolve this.

Comment: @BenRethmeier try the process that I have written below

Comment: Thanks Rafael for providing the help on this issue. This issue has been documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551(v=vs.140).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. run following command to install cordova globally

   **`npm install -g cordova`**
2. Then create new cordova project using

   **`cordova start project_name`**
3. Go to directory and Install plugin using

   **`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`**
4. Copy Installed folder org.apache.cordova.file & paste into plugins folder in Visual Studio solution (Create plugins folder in root if not exist).

Update config file

```
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />
```

5. Build the Project

OR

Simply Add Following Lines in Config.xml.

```
<vs:features>
    <vs:feature>https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git</vs:feature>
</vs:features>
```

Build the project and observe bld/debug/plugins folder

One of two ways should work for you

Comment: Thanks, manually installing the plugin I wanted with cordova plugin add, and then copying the folder and then using the 'Local' grab in visual studios config.xml UI (which probably just adds the line you noted) appears to have worked for me.

Comment: Ya its work but plugins like file will take long time than usual...better  to edit config file and add plugin name and version as I mention above...Visual Studio does same thing..Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

There currently is an issue with plugin history in the official Cordova plugin repository that is likely causing this error.

Use a git URI instead to get the latest plugin by entering it into the custom tab.

Ex: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

You can find the git URIs here: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device

**Update 2/16 12:55pm PT: Plugin history is in the process of being restored. VS pinned plugins are working as of this time. You should no longer need to use this workaround.**

Comment: Also - This will only happen to you if you haven't previously downloaded a plugin because they are cached locally.  You can watch progress via this Cordova mailing list thread. http://callback.markmail.org/message/wfpjqkjr2pyiairr

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what broke this exactly, but this workaround should do the trick:

At the command line:

```
> npm install -g cordova
> mkdir cordovaTemp
> cd cordovaTemp
> cordova create .
> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Next, copy & paste the cordovaTemp/plugins sub-folders into your project's /plugins folder, and then do the following in Visual Studio:

- Open the config.xml file
- Navigate to Plugins > Custom
- Select the Local radio button
- Click the ... icon to browse for the new sub-folder under your project's plugins folder

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem. Even by adding the git address in the `config.xml` manually wasn't working for me.

The problem is that I am behind a corporate proxy and even though my npm and visual studio are configured to that proxy, my git wasn't and this process uses the git clone function.

To solve I've just had to add my proxy configurations in my git:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@my.proxy.com:1234
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@my.proxy.com:1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with Cordova Tools. I'm also behind a corporate proxy, after tried the solutions above I had to create the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY enviroment variable.

HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport
HTTPS_PROXY = http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport
Where your username:password is your login credentials.

My visual studio, npm and git proxy settings were also set up.